# File uploaded to S3 is different from original one

Tags: amazon-web-services, react-native, amazon-s3, xmlhttprequest, expo

I am uploading a file with XMLHTTPRequest from within a React Native app to S3 directly with presigned URL, the problem is the file uploaded to S3 is quite different from the original file, the XMLHTTPReqeust part looks pretty much like http://blog.rudikovac.com/react-native-upload-any-file-to-s3-with-a-presigned-url/. Two files are quite different in terms of size

`$ ls -alh remote.jpeg local.jpg
-rw-r--r--  1 hao  staff    55K 10 Jul 09:47 local.jpg
-rw-r--r--@ 1 hao  staff   215K 10 Jul 09:48 remote.jpeg`

Answer (score 0):

I reckon it's because the Expo ImagePicker compresses the image when I select one from Library, for PNG image, it's OK since there's no compression at all, but for JPEG (which is default format in iOS when taking photos), it will compress the image, I am wondering if there's a way of letting Expo ImagePicker stop the compression, it happens even after I set the `quality` option to be 1.0